# How to write recursive function that find the LCS between two null-terminated strings in assembly

Tags: memory

I am using MARS Assembler and Runtime Simulator.
I alway have memory issues.

Assemble: operation completed successfully.

Go: running assign2_lcs.s

Error in C:\Users\HP Laptop\Downloads\Assembly Assignment 2,\assign2_lcs.s line 17: Runtime exception at 0x00400010: address out of range 0x00000000

Go: execution terminated with errors.

I tried to revise the code to many different ways.

Here is my complere code:

.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter the first string (max 1024 characters): "
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter the second string (max 1024 characters): "
result: .asciiz "The length of LCS is: "

.text
.globl find_lcs

find_lcs:
# Prologue
addi $sp, $sp, -12
sw $ra, 0($sp)
sw $a0, 4($sp)
sw $a1, 8($sp)

```
# Load arguments
lw $a0, 0($a0)     # Load address of the first string
lw $a1, 0($a1)     # Load address of the second string

# Check for null pointers
beqz $a0, end_lcs  # If first string is null, return 0
beqz $a1, end_lcs  # If second string is null, return 0

# Base case: if either string is empty, return 0
lb $t0, 0($a0)     # Load byte from the first string
beq $t0, $zero, end_lcs   # If byte is null, return 0
lb $t0, 0($a1)     # Load byte from the second string
beq $t0, $zero, end_lcs   # If byte is null, return 0

# Compare the first characters of both strings
lb $t0, 0($a0)
lb $t1, 0($a1)
beq $t0, $t1, equal_chars

# If characters are not equal, find LCS by considering both cases
# Case 1: Exclude first character of s1
addi $a0, $a0, 1
jal find_lcs
move $s0, $v0     # Store result in $s0

# Case 2: Exclude first character of s2
lw $a0, 4($sp)    # Reload s1
addi $a1, $a1, 1
jal find_lcs
move $s1, $v0     # Store result in $s1

# Choose the maximum LCS
bge $s0, $s1, end_lcs
move $v0, $s1
j end_lcs
```

equal_chars:
# Characters are equal, move to the next characters
addi $a0, $a0, 1
addi $a1, $a1, 1
jal find_lcs
addi $v0, $v0, 1   # Increment LCS by 1
j end_lcs

end_lcs:
# Epilogue
lw $ra, 0($sp)
lw $a0, 4($sp)
lw $a1, 8($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 12
jr $ra

## Test function

main:
# Prompt user for the first string
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt1
syscall

```
# Read the first string
li $v0, 8
la $a0, 0x10010000   # Buffer for the first string
li $a1, 1024
syscall

# Prompt user for the second string
li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt2
syscall

# Read the second string
li $v0, 8
la $a0, 0x10020000   # Buffer for the second string
li $a1, 1024
syscall

# Call find_lcs
la $a0, 0x10010000   # Address of the first string
la $a1, 0x10020000   # Address of the second string
jal find_lcs

# Print the result
li $v0, 4
la $a0, result
syscall

# Print the length of the LCS
move $a0, $v0
li $v0, 1
syscall

# Exit
li $v0, 10
syscall
```